# Eclipse Servers view not showing added Tomcat runtime environment

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I am running Eclipse Helios SR2 (the EE version) on Ubuntu 11.04. 
I installed tomcat6.0.29 manually and can start/ stop it ok.
I can add the Tomcat 6 Server Runtime environment successfully to eclipse - I've never had the "Cannot create the server" problem however the environment **never** show up in my Servers view.

I've tried many avenues but no success (same issue with installing the aptitude tomcat6 and creating links etc)
Any suggestions on how to progress this ?

Other info:I have exactly the same issue with a brand new install of Eclipse Indigo (the EE version)

I have java-6-sun installed:

update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.5.0-sun 53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
java-6-sun 63 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

Comment: So right-click in `Servers` view and then `New ...` does not work?

Comment: Thanks my first foray into EE - I thought I was creating a new local server instance each time I did that (as it then subsequently threw an exception when starting the tomcat instance). When I created a new Servlet project from scratch eveything worked ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem a week ago (on Ubuntu 11.04). I failed to find why it doesn't show the servers in the view - they appear in the Servers project. But I fixed it by switching to a fresh workspace.

(Of course, assuming you have right-clicked in the server view and chose "New -> server")

Comment: This is really annoying bug. I'm wondering what (configuration?) file is responsible for this

Answer (score 0):

Well I was inspecting what might be the issue. I was able to add a runtime but cannot add a new server.

Changing permissions of Tomcat configuration files solved the issue for me (without creating a new workspace)

```
chmod 664 /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/*
```

It seems that if you add runtime that cannot read configuration, you are not able add such server under "Servers" window...